# How much juice can you get from an orange?

Tags: oranges, juicing

I wanted to make fresh orange juice using a squeezer and wanted to know how many oranges it takes to make an 8oz glass of juice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you know better than I do, it depends on the orange and type of orange. My mom, an executive chef, used to say that you'd allow 1-2 lb of oranges for 1 drinkable cup of orange juice.

I really think, that it's highly dependent on the type of orange. I know naval and blood oranges are the juiciest compared to other varieties.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of juice you get from an orange will depend on a number or things:

- Size of the orange
- Juice content of the orange
- Whether you use the pulp or remove all the bits

May be you should be asking what oranges are best for producing the most amount of juice and how do I get the most juice from them?

The easiest way to find out how many oranges you need is to buy a bag of them and then start squeezing till you have a glass full :)

Answer (score 4):

A medium sized orange will have roughly 2 oz of juice.

Comment: Which is just a tad shy of a 0,6 dl.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get more juice from citrus is to juice it when warm. Cold fruit doesn't release as much juice. I put a skewer hole in my citrus (for safety issues) and then microwave the fruit for 20=30 seconds before cutting and juicing.

I'm also partial to Valencia oranges for juice.

Comment: i also microwave citrus for 15-30 seconds (depending on size) before squeezing, especially if i'm using my hands instead of a juicer.

Answer (score 2):

With a masticating juicer, I've averaged 56% juice from unpeeled oranges (navel).

Answer (score -1):

This will depend upon various factors and some of them I will list here:

- The freshness of the orange
- The size of the orange
- The type of the orange
- The type of the juicer

When it comes to freshness the main problem here is that oranges lose a certain percentage of their juices if they stay for too long. Basically, they dry like everything else.. No brainer really..

The size of the orange is the obvious one.

Now when it comes to the juicer type there are really many if them out there but you should be looking for the citrus juicer. Citrus juicers are designed to extract the most out of citrus fruit such as oranges. Usually most of them will do the work but I recommend the one I linked. You can also take a look at masticating juicers because they are known for their ability to extract the juice with no loss in quality. Besides masticating juicer can squeeze every drop out of the orange, but you will have to peel it. Still this can be profitable because if you buy 5 oranges you will want to drink as much juice as possible and leave little to none to waste.